# Error trying to connect to table in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server, azure

I have been able to successfully connect to a Microsoft SQL Server in R using `dbConnect()` from `DBI`.

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),"IMOS_DWH_PROD",
                 uid = "xxxx",
                 pwd = "xxxx")
```

I can also list all the tables using

```
#List the tables in the database
tables <- dbListTables(con)
```

However when I try to connect to a table using

```
tbl(con, "V_Dim_Voyage")
```

I get the following error:-

```
Error: <SQL> 'SELECT *
FROM "V_Dim_Voyage" AS "zzz6"
WHERE (0 = 1)'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42S02: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'V_Dim_Voyage'.
```

I am on a virtual machine (Ubuntu 16.04) and connected to Azure Data Warehouse. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the result of `dbListTables`. If many tables, show where *V_Dim_Voyage* appears. Try to match case exactly.

Comment: There are 890 tables and the name is exact. I tried it on other tables too but got the same error.

Comment: Are all tables on the same schema? And not to belabor,  can you still post the header of the output and about 5 rows where *V_Dim_Voyage* shows?

Comment: @Parfait thanks for pointing this out! Apparently there are 23 different schemas and this table is in a specific schema. Could finally connect by `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA")

tbl(con, dbplyr::in_schema("Pres",  "V_Dim_Voyage"))`